# Build a dictionary from a string using regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

Say I have this string:

```
var results = 
[{\r\n    \"ninja\": \"Leonardo - $0.99\",\r\n    \"data\": [[1336485655241,0.99],[1336566333236,0.99],[1336679536073,0.99],[1336706394834,0.99],[1336774593068,0.99],[1366284992043,0.99]]},
\r\n{\r\n    \"ninja\": \"Donatello - $0.25\",\r\n    \"data\": [[1361061084420,0.23],[1366102471587,0.25],[1366226367262,0.25],[1366284992043,0.25]]},
\r\n{\r\n    \"ninja\": \"Raphael - $0.15\",\r\n    \"data\": [[1327305600000,0.15], [1365583220422,0.15],[1365669396241,0.15],[1365669396241,0.15],[1365753433493,0.15],[1366284992043,0.15]]},\r\n\
r\n{\r\n    \"ninja\": \"Michelangelo - $0.14\",\r\n    \"data\": [1366284992043,0.14]]};
```

I wanted to build a dictionary that would store the names of the ninjas and their price, so that I would have:

Key \ Value

Leonardo \ 0.99

Donatello \ 0.25

Raphael \ 0.15

Michelangelo \ 0.14

So I have been reading a LOT since a few days about regex, and I don't know how it works yet. Up to now I have this line of code:

```
var dictNinjas = Regex.Matches(priceListValue, @"\*(\w+)=(a-zA-Z)|\*(\$(0-9))").Cast<Match>()
                                        .ToDictionary(x => x.Groups[0].Value,
                                                      x => x.Groups[1].Value);
```

My comprehension was that is would first seek all words with letters a-zA-Z, then all values located right after the $ symbol. The | symbol is the grouping, so the first parameters was group 0 and the second parameter would be group 1. But this does not work.

Can anyone help me out? I'm trying hard to understand how to make this work, thank you.

Comment: Where is this string coming from?

Comment: You string looks like a JSon string. Should't you use a json deserializer?

Comment: @DGibbs Parsing through a html document using html agility pack, a string I got from a node.

Comment: @SteveB It is highly possible, I don't know because I don't know JSon

Comment: @HerveS It looks like json to me, check out [json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

Comment: Sounds cool, I'll check this out. If I use json.net, how could I do this?

Comment: Read [this previous SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1212115/588868)

Comment: I see a couple of things in the RegEx that need changing: 1. in two places you have accidentally escaped the `*` character, so you are saying "zero or more `\ ` characters". You need `\\*` instead of `\*`.  2. `(0-9)` matches the string "0-9", but it looks like you want any digit; use `[0-9]` instead (or `[0-9]*` or `[0-9]+`) -- the same thing goes for `(a-zA-Z)`.  There may be something else, but those are the first things I saw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Groups[0].Value` is the whole match, so you need `1` and `2`

```
var dictNinjas = Regex.Matches(str, @"""(\w+) - \$([\d.]+)").Cast<Match>()
                                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Groups[1].Value,
                                                  x => x.Groups[2].Value);
```

`Groups[1].Value` refers to the content captured in the first `()` in the regex, and `` `Groups[2].Value `` the second.

I am not sure why you have a `=` in your regex but t looks like you have misunderstood something along the way.

Comment: `([\d.]+)` could match things like `1..231.21399..` but as long as the inputs are carefully typed it should be fine.

Comment: Actually, this works fine! So let me resume: first, @MikeM, you are right: it's my first "try" with Regex and my comprehension is... close to nothing. So now, I think that this looks for any complete words (the \w looks for words, though I don't know what the + does exactly), then follows up to look for any $ sign and any numbers (The d sign) located right after. Right?

Comment: @Izzy. Yes, I agree that something like `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` would be better.

Comment: @MikeM `(\d+\.\d{2})` is the simplest safe option I've found.

Comment: @HerveS.  `\w` means any word character, i.e. a letter, digit or `_`, and `+` means _one or more_. `\d+` means one or more digits.

Comment: Thanks! My understanding of regex leveled up because of you both, so thanks a lot.

Comment: @MikeM It would only match if there were two digits, but if there were more it would still only match those two. I try to shy away from using `+?` and `+*` as much as possible.. but if you need the extra accuracy with your currency values then `(\d+\.\d\d+)` should be fine. (`(\d+\.\d+?)` stops after the first digit after the `.`)

Comment: @HerveS Check out http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm, it will help a load (has a neat little tool to test your RE too)

Comment: @MikeM I have a question: Say that I add another value looking like this:\r\n{\r\n    \"label\": \"AAAA Team FourA - $19.98\",\r\n    \"data\": [[1350156916637,24.98],[1350303087864,24.98],[1351125084705,24.98],[1351370833325,24.98], you Regex does not catch him since CCG is not a word, how could I included these?

Comment: @HerveS. Where is CCG? I am not sure what you mean, but if you change `(\w+)` to `(.+?)` it will match several words not just one.

Comment: My mistake, I mean AAAA Team. It's because AAAA doesn't make a word, I think it skips this possibility.

Comment: Worked perfectly, that was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly:

> so the first parameters was group 0 and the second parameter would be
>   group 1

- Group 0 is the whole matched string
- Group 1 is the group that connects to the first close bracket.

Don't worry, it's a common mistake to make.

This site has a [very handy regex tester tool](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm) as well as lots of RE info - just remember that when you put your Regular expression search string into C# you might need to escape some more characters and verbatim might not interpret things correctly.

For example: I plug `(\w+) - \$(\d+\.\d{2})` is as my RE string and get:

> First match: Leonardo - $0.99 at position 24
>   Backreferences: $1 = Leonardo $2 = 0.99
>   Additional matches:
>   Found: Donatello - $0.25 at position 217
>   Found: Raphael - $0.15 at position 369
>   Found: Michelangelo - $0.14 at position 566